# Can the Mind Sharpener infusion be used in tandem with an Armor infusion?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, artificer, artificer-infusions

One of the new Artificer infusions from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* is the Mind Sharpener, requiring "A suit of armor or robes". There are other Artificer infusions that apply onto armor, such as the Armor of Magical Strength, requiring "A suit of armor".

Can an Artificer wear robes on top of (or underneath) a suit of armor, infuse the robes with "Mind Sharpener" and infuse the armor with another armor infusion (to benefit from both infusions and the armor's other properties as per normal) ?

Comment: Related: "[How do the Armorer artificer's Arcane Armor and Armor Modifications features interact with the ability to wear magic boots/gloves/etc.?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177914)"

Answer (score 4):

#### It's up to the DM to use common sense.

"Use common sense" is exactly the guidance given in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (p. 141), under ["Multiple Items of the Same Kind"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#MultipleItemsoftheSameKind):

> Use common sense to determine whether more than one of a given kind of magic item can be worn. A character can’t normally wear more than one pair of footwear, one pair of gloves or gauntlets, one pair of bracers, one suit of armor, one item of headwear, and one cloak. You can make exceptions; a character might be able to wear a circlet under a helmet, for example, or be able to layer two cloaks.

It's up to the DM to decide if you can wear robes over your armor.