# Does Armor Modifications allow for multiple infusion on the same area?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

A bit of a oddly phrased question however, the *Armored Modification* ability for the *Armorer* subclass for the *Artificer* says...

> At 9th level, you learn how to use your artificer infusions to specially modify your Arcane Armor. That armor now counts as separate items for the purposes of your Infuse Items feature: armor (the chest piece), boots, helmet, and the armor's special weapon.

So if, for example, I used one infusion to create *Boots of Elvenkind* and put them in the "boots" section **of the Arcane Armor**, could I then use another infusion on a different pair of boots to created *Winged Boots* and put the infused armor on my *actual* feet and gain the benefits of both items? One on mey boots,and one on my Arcane Armor?

Comment: Some interesting and question-clarifying conversation can be found [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131487/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-youjay).

Answer (score -4):

### RAW, yes

Nothing in the ability description prevents you from wearing magic items as normal on your feet, head, and hands.

### RAI, your DM may vary (YDMMV)

As [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177914/how-do-the-armorer-artificers-arcane-armor-and-armor-modifications-features-int) illustrates, based on what exactly your character is attempting to wear simultaneously, a DM may or may not grant this combination of infusions based on the [rules for wearing multiple items of the same kind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#MultipleItemsoftheSameKind).

Anecdotally, my DM who is usually a bit of a stickler for RAI permits our Artificer to wear Winged Boots in addition to her Arcane Armor, because they're flavored as leather "underboots".